# Kali linux update

Tags: linux

i am the new user for kali linux. i installed kali in my vmware and i try to update  using this command "apt-get update". while running this command i'm getting some error like "Err:6 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid:" and i tried to resolve that issue. so i am using this command "wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add". after i ran this "wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add" command also getting same error. i couldn't install any softwares in kali linux..and i am confused for repository links.. any one kindly list out the repository links.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The specifics of this question aside, Kali Linux is a niche Linux distro, which you may be using with the full knowledge of what it is and for particular reasons- if so, please disregard this comment! If not, I would strongly recommend reading [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me) over on Unix & Linux StackExchange. **It could save you a lot of time and hassle** :)

Comment: Check the guide https://www.cyberpratibha.com/blog/how-to-update-and-upgrade-kali-linux-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check your package list and try to below commmands in your terminal;

- `apt-get clean` removes all packages from the package cache.  it will cause you to redownload any packages you need to install a program.
- `sudo apt-get update` Linux systems require package repositories to keep themselves up to date and keep a list of these repositories in `“/etc/apt/source.list”` or `/etc/apt/preferences`.. It downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies.
- `sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrades all installed packages.
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`  it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary
- `sudo apt-get install -f` the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

---

If problem is not resolved, try to below solution:

- `wget 'https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add archive-key.asc` to resolve "the following signatures were invalid"
- `apt-key fingerprint` to validate package authenticity
- Reinstall your kali linux image. [Kali linux custome image](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/)